# Metro App development and Remote Database Connections

Tags: c#, .net, sql, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a web matrix-based site I originally created, and then continued development in Visual Studio Ultimate. Now that the website is complete, I am making a Metro app for Windows 8 release preview.

I need the Metro app to connect to a remote SQL database - but connecting to remote (or any kind of,) databases in Metro apps seems to be impossible. Is there any way to connect to a remote database from within a Metro app, without the use of Services or Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to connect to a remote database within a Metro app, without the use of Services or Azure?

I'm going to assume by 'services' you mean web services. In that case, there isn't really an alternative. You'll have to use WCF or otherwise create some kind of web service to access the database. WinRT is in the same situation as Silverlight in this regard.

Comment: Ah crap. I've been searching for remote DB support for months. What a disappointment. I can't believe that Microsoft would make such a stupid decision. No DB connections from a Windows app? Pfft. I might as well switch over to a MAC, I here its users are pretty damn happy these days.